# Как повесить веб сервис на 80 порт?

Tags: asp.net, c#, .net, iis, wcf

Добрый день! Нужно повесить веб сервис на определённый порт - 80. Это делается настройкой сервера или проекта и как? Не могу найти в сети ответ, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто зайти в IIS и добавить новый сайт, стандартно для протокола HTTP будет установлен порт 80

Answer (score 0):

В настройка проекта вы задаёте, где будет расположен (хоститься) ваш сервис - т.е. что-то типа http://localhost/myservice.svc. Так же нужно убедиться, что данный URL доступен, т.е. веб сервер, который будет хостить ваш сервис, имеет возможность привязаться к этому адресу. По умолчанию Visual Studio скорее всего предлагает хостить на Development Server'e, но я бы посоветовал перейти на полноценный IIS, на первом этапе так будет проще. Кроме того, нужно помнить, что в системе два различных приложения не могут использовать один и тот же порт. Не раз сталкивался с тем, что Skype по умолчанию настроен на использование 80-го порта, и когда IIS пытается запуститься, то сайты или сервисы, находящиеся на 80-м порте - не работают.

Answer (score 0):

IIS по умолчанию слушает именно 80-й порт. Достаточно просто создать новый Application, указав путь к папке сервиса.

Если не слушает (например, конфигурация нестандартная) - то настроить порт можно через IIS Manager, выбрав сайт в дереве, и нажав `Bindings...` в панеле `Actions` справа.